# How do I get X11 WM_CLASS for active window using JNA (Java)?

Tags: java, x11, jna

I use the following code to get the current (in focus) window in Linux:

```
X11 x11 = X11.INSTANCE;
X11.Display display = x11.XOpenDisplay(null);
X11.Window window = x11.XDefaultRootWindow(display);
```

Now I'd like to get `WM_CLASS` property of this window.

In [Setting and Reading the WM_CLASS Property](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/wm-class.html#XClassHint) there is a following passage showing how to do this:

> To read a window's WM_CLASS property, use XGetClassHint().
>
> The XClassHint contains:
>
> typedef struct {
>
> char *res_name;
>
> char *res_class;
>
> } XClassHint;

However, when we look at [X11.XWMHints (JNA API)](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.1.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/unix/X11.XWMHints.html) we can see that there is no such a property `res_class` (that is, `WM_CLASS`).

So, how do get the `WM_CLASS` property of the current window?

Comment: Did you try `String wc = new X.Window(new X.Display(display), window).getWindowClass();` from `jnacontrib`? https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/x11/src/jnacontrib/x11/api/X.java#L591 it reads `WM_CLASS` property from current window. The result string should contain two strings, `X.Display` class replaces `\0` char with a dot (`.`) https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/x11/src/jnacontrib/x11/api/X.java#L932

Comment: Yes, it did try. It works fine. However, I like to know how it could be done manually without using that code. AFAIK it uses some functions that are already implemented by JNA like string conversion you have mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `getWindowClass()` [method](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/x11/src/jnacontrib/x11/api/X.java#L591) of `X.Window` class from `jnacontrib` package: it reads `WC_CLASS` [property](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#WM_CLASS) from provided window and replaces null-terminator characters (`\0`) with dots (`.`). Javadoc [says](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/x11/src/jnacontrib/x11/api/X.java#L939):

> Returns the property value as UTF8 string where every '\0' character is replaced by '.'.

```java
X11 x11 = X11.INSTANCE;
X11.Display display = x11.XOpenDisplay(null);
X11.Window window = x11.XDefaultRootWindow(display);
String wmClass = new X.Window(new X.Display(display), window).getWindowClass();
```

---

Another way to get this value is to read it manually (copied some parts from contrib package):

```java
    static class XClassHint {
        public final String resName;
        public final String resClass;

        public XClassHint(final String name, final String cls) {
            this.resName = name;
            this.resClass = cls;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s:%s", this.resName, this.resClass);
        }
    }

    private static XClassHint wmClass(X11 x11, X11.Display display, X11.Window window) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        final X11.Atom xa_prop_type = X11.XA_STRING;
        final X11.Atom xa_prop_name = X11.XA_WM_CLASS;
        final int MAX_PROPERTY_VALUE_LEN = 4096;

        X11.AtomByReference xa_ret_type_ref = new X11.AtomByReference();
        IntByReference ret_format_ref = new IntByReference();
        NativeLongByReference ret_nitems_ref = new NativeLongByReference();
        NativeLongByReference ret_bytes_after_ref = new NativeLongByReference();
        PointerByReference ret_prop_ref = new PointerByReference();

        NativeLong long_offset = new NativeLong(0);
        NativeLong long_length = new NativeLong(MAX_PROPERTY_VALUE_LEN / 4);

        if (x11.XGetWindowProperty(display, window, xa_prop_name, long_offset, long_length, false,
            xa_prop_type, xa_ret_type_ref, ret_format_ref,
            ret_nitems_ref, ret_bytes_after_ref, ret_prop_ref) != X11.Success) {
            String prop_name = x11.XGetAtomName(display, xa_prop_name);
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot get " + prop_name + " property.");
        }

        X11.Atom xa_ret_type = xa_ret_type_ref.getValue();
        Pointer ret_prop = ret_prop_ref.getValue();

        if (xa_ret_type == null) {
            //the specified property does not exist for the specified window
            return null;
        }

        if (xa_prop_type == null ||
            !xa_ret_type.toNative().equals(xa_prop_type.toNative())) {
            x11.XFree(ret_prop);
            String prop_name = x11.XGetAtomName(display, xa_prop_name);
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid type of " + prop_name + " property");
        }

        int ret_format = ret_format_ref.getValue();
        long ret_nitems = ret_nitems_ref.getValue().longValue();

        // null terminate the result to make string handling easier
        int nbytes;
        if (ret_format == 32)
            nbytes = Native.LONG_SIZE;
        else if (ret_format == 16)
            nbytes = Native.LONG_SIZE / 2;
        else if (ret_format == 8)
            nbytes = 1;
        else if (ret_format == 0)
            nbytes = 0;
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid return format");
        int length = Math.min((int) ret_nitems * nbytes, MAX_PROPERTY_VALUE_LEN);

        byte[] ret = ret_prop.getByteArray(0, length);

        x11.XFree(ret_prop);
        if( ret == null ){
            return null;
        }

        // search for '\0'
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
            if (ret[i] == '\0') {
                ret[i] = '.';
            }
        }

        String wcSrc = new String(ret, "UTF8");
        final String[] parts = wcSrc.split("\\.");
        return new XClassHint(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, is there a way to not use this class?

Comment: @menteith sure, you can create a class to reflect `WM_CLASS` struct and read properties manually (see update)